# Multiple array inputs for Google Sheets custom function that divides one array by another

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Building a running log in Google Sheets and need to write a function that returns the pace (minutes per mile) in a separate column adjacent to the two columns with distance (miles) and duration (minute) entries.

Duration data is stored in column B.
Distance data is stored in column C.
Pace data is returned to column D.

I can successfully return an array to column D that doubles the duration value for each row in column B:

```
function calculatePace(distance, duration){    
  if(distance.map){
  return distance.map(calculatePace);
  }
  else{
    var pace = duration*2;
    return pace;
  }
}
```

What I really need is to divide the duration array by distance array, such that

```
else{
  var pace = duration/distance;
  return pace;
}
```

But I do not know how to recurse the `calculatePace` function so that each row in distance.map and duration.map are both passed for each call.

To further clarify, `=calculatePace(B1:B10, C1:C10)` would be stored in cell D1.

Answer (score 1):

You want a Google Sheets function that divides one array by another. The built-in `arrayformula` does this already:

```
=arrayformula(B1:B10/C1:C10)
```

But if a custom function is required (perhaps it's a part of a larger computation), it would look like this:

```
function calculatePace(distance, duration){    
  if (distance.map && duration.map && distance.length == duration.length) {
    return distance.map(function(a, i) {
      return a[0]/duration[i][0];
    });
  }
  else if (!distance.map && !duration.map) {
    return distance/duration;
  }
  else { 
    throw new Error('The arguments must have the same number of rows');
  }
}
```

The essential part is the division of arrays,

```
distance.map(function(a, i) {
  return a[0]/duration[i][0];
});
```

Here `a` is a row from the first range, so `a[0]` accesses its first element. The matching element of duration array is `duration[i][0]`. Since the ranges are presumed to be columns, only the first column is considered.

The if-statements check that inputs are either arrays of the same length or scalars; otherwise an error is thrown.